# 'git pull' on Windows7 frozen process 'git-am.exe'

Tags: windows, git, github, cmd, git-bash

when I need a pull for remote repo, the command 'git pull' dosen't work.
Only create a processe 'git-am.exe' but nothing happens

On Win7 whit git:

```
$ git version 
git version 2.8.0.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if you have any remote set in your git? by `git remote -v` if not, do set remote in order to get pull request.